# Where are Data Sources of WSO2 Data Services Server stored?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am wondering where are WSO2 DSS **Data Sources** that user manually added stored? In a H2 database or in some XML?

I am getting error that the Carbon Data Source X cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add them from UI, they will be stored in registry in location - /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I found my data source in REG_CONTENT table.

You can find all data sources using SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM regdb.REG_CONTENT where REG_CONTENT_DATA like '%datasource%';
```